# AngularJS frontend and Rails backend with AWS in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to discuss about `AngularJS` and `Ruby on Rails` working together and deployed in AWS (Amazon Web Services).

So far, I have a development environment with an AngularJS frontend that sends request to a Ruby on Rails API backend. These both are two separate applications (they are in separated git repositories).

The `AngularJS` app is running in a `Node.js` server listening on one port, and `Rails` is running in a `Webrick` server listening on another port.

Although they work together, AngularJS is not physically integrated in the RoR app.

Now its time to deploy in production environment. For that, I will use an `EC2 AWS` instance (currently deploying using Elastic Beanstalk). As far as I understand, I can't have the same architecture here.

I would like to know your suggestions this point. Do you see any advantages or disadvantages?

Should I update my development environment, so the `AngularJS` app is integrated inside the `RoR` application (and deploy just one application)?

This is something I don't like, because I guess I have to modify many things.

On the other hand, is it possible to run both applications separately, the same way I do in development?

Can I install a `node.js` and a `Unicorn` or whichever server manually in production in the same instance?

Comment: Can you explain why you _can't_ have the same architecture on AWS? Is it because you can't run two servers? There's nothing on the AWS side that would prevent this from happening. In fact, my current job deploys nearly identical to this on AWS (our front end is hosted on on their CloudFront, though).

Comment: Hi Jason, I dont say it is not possible. The only problem is Im new with AWS, so, so far I only know how to deploy with Elastic Beanstalk. With EB I dont know how to do it if possible. I think in order to have this architechture I should create an EC2 instance and install the servers manually. Is it right? How should I do it?

Comment: we have trying to install node js on elastic beanstalk but no success almost the same requirement like you AngularJS app is running in a Node.js and backend on php. We have try to use .ebextension to install node js but still have limitation and issue to we decided to do manually. My Suggest is go manually for this setup. Any other thing you need to know about AWS elastic beanstalk let me know

Comment: @Rober I'm not really an ops guy, so I wouldn't know how to setup EC2.. at least not the specifics of it. You're going to need two servers (or, even just 1 if you wanna run these apps on separate ports), one configured for node and one for Rails. I know their OpsWork stuff makes things like deploying Rails and Node really simple. From there you'd just configure the Node server to point to the Rails server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally deployed with two separated applications as described above. The main difference is around the servers. My AngularJS frontend finally runs on an Nginx. And my Rails API is running on a Unicorn.

Comment: Can you provide detailed step on how did you achieved this or a blog post explaining the solution. Thank you.